# Pip Install Modified MLflow Fork

Tags: git, pip, installation

I'm currently trying to pip install a fork of mlflow that I have created and modified. I'm changing some of the functionality to match what I need.

How do I install my forked repo instead of the default `pip install mlflow`? I put a few print statements in the functions I modified but I'm not seeing them when I run my mlflow.

I'm trying to use `pip install git+https://github.com/<MY_USERNAME>/mlflow.git@master`

Comment: The last command looks good. What was the outcome? If `mlflow` was already installed you need `pip install -U` to replace it.

Comment: I'm installing and running mlflow on a docker image. I just don't understand why my changes are not reflecting when I run the code.